# Nodejs writing a scraper that can read JS protected websites

Tags: node.js, npm, web-scraping, scraper

nodejs is new for me, and I've just started learning web scrapers. The problem is that I need to scrap a website that is protected with JS. So I need to get phones from the website, but div with the phone number appears only after user clicks on "show number" button. Are there any ways or npm to get the numbers? Here is the website [enter link description here](http://www.kz.all.biz/search/enterprises/?q=%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BE), but it is in russian language. So the button is "показать телефоны". Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are going to want to use a tool like selenium to do the scraping.. it works on sites with dynamically generated data as well as interact with the site using data entry and virtual mouse interactions.

Answer (score 1):

Go to the page with the phone numbers and open the console and look at your network tools.  When you click on a phone number it makes an ajax request and gives you a nice formatted response

```
{"status":"ok","phone":"+7 (727) 317-20-86","html_tooltip":"<section class=\"company-phones-tooltip\">\r\n    <div class=\"company-phones-tooltip__wrap\">\r\n        <header class=\"company-phones-tooltip__header\">\r\n            Inform the manager that you learned the information on Allbiz.\r\n        <\/header>\r\n        <ul class=\"company-phones-tooltip-list\">\r\n                            <li class=\"company-phones-tooltip-list__item\">\r\n                    <div class=\"company-phones-tooltip-list__name\">\r\n                        management\r\n                    <\/div>\r\n                    <div class=\"company-phones-tooltip-list__number\">\r\n                        +7 (727) 317-20-86\r\n                    <\/div>\r\n                <\/li>\r\n                    <\/ul>\r\n        <footer class=\"company-phones-tooltip__footer\">\r\n            <a class=\"company-phones-tooltip__link\" href=\"https:\/\/12246-kz.all.biz\/contacts\" target=\"_blank\">\r\n                Show all contacts\r\n            <\/a>\r\n        <\/footer>\r\n    <\/div>\r\n<\/section>"}
```

In order to emulate this you just need to make a call to the http://api.all.biz/ajax/viewphonenew/kz endpoint with the correct parameters after scraping the page.  And all the query params that are needed for this endpoint is in the html element.

```
<div class="company-phones__wrap" data-click="company-phones" data-entid="58474" data-verify="bYjmFpAfm5QWOgIjx8cyNOARdSG3FIoPo6he2dYGLIc=" data-phone="Zk6xDyCXPMqWMXgTaCI51A24FHIsDwuy8IaF993LsHI=" data-country="kz" data-placement="company-phones-tooltip___3" data-tooltip-direction="left" data-source="list">
        <div class="company-phones__code">+7(7&nbsp;</div>
        <div class="company-phones__main" data-ga="show-phones-list" data-ga-id="">
            <div class="company-phones__btn">Показать телефоны</div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, I tried to do so, but it outputs only "error request"

Comment: have you tried this method? did it worked for you? maybe I made something wrong